# How I can have separate cookies for separate SPAs calling same API in OAUTH/BFF pattern?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cookies, oauth-2.0

I have API gateway at `api.myapp.com`, two SPAs served by CloudFront CDN (from S3 buckets) `spa1.myapp.com` and `spa2.myapp.com` and authorization server `auth.myapp.com`. So API GW, SPAs and auth server have same root domain.

Whenever user logs in on any SPA, SPA redirects user to authorization server which then redirects user back to SPA setting session cookies (HttpOnly, Secure, SameSite = Strict) on the way. There is OAUTH2 server behind authorization server and what I want here is to use OAUTH/BFF (backend for frontend) pattern.

Now I am not sure if `auth.myapp.com` can set session cookie for `spa1.myapp.com` to be used for `api.myapp.com`, but same session cookie should not be passed to `api.myapp.com` when request comes from other SPA (`spa2.myapp.com`).

From what I understand I will need some reverse-proxies, but I am kind of lost where those should be added (in front of which services).

My idea is to have to reverse-proxies:

- `spa1.myapp.com/api` => `api.myapp.com`
- `spa2.myapp.com/api` => `api.myapp.com`

And those reverse proxies would pass cookies set for domain `spa*.myapp.com` to `api.myapp.com` (as token instead of cookie).

But not sure what to do with `auth.myapp.com` - do I need any reverse-proxy to set cookies for `spa*.myapp.com/api` when redirecting back from `auth.myapp.com` to `spa*.myapp.com`?

Also is it possible to have for example `spa1.myapp.com/api` => `api.myapp.com` reverse-proxy while still serving SPA from CloudFront CDN?

Below image how I understand BFF pattern should work:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to use an API driven flow to solve the problem of a CDN deployed SPA that uses secure cookies:

- The Authorization Server is an out of the box component that you do not own or control the code for, so do not try to use it to set SPA cookies
- Cloudfront cannot (easily) set cookies for an SPA since Cloudfront's role is just to make static content available
- However, an API can set cookies for the SPA, though it is a slightly tricky flow
- The browser should call API entry points directly rather than routing API requests via Cloudfront.
- The API gateway entry point URLs used by the SPA can be different to the physical API URLs.

**TOKEN HANDLER PATTERN**

See the [Curity code example](https://curity.io/resources/learn/token-handler-spa-example/) for how all parts fit together. Utility APIs and gateways can be the best option to do the OAuth work and to handle cookies when APIs are called.

**AWS SPA**

See also my [AWS SPA](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample.final) for a working version you can run. My domain setup is the same as yours I think.

**MULTIPLE APPS**

You would handle this via multiple API routes, which is also how websites work and you need to think through API / cookie paths and domains that will best enable you to scale your architecture. In AWS I have a preference for the first of these, since domains can be spun up easily.

- https://api.myproduct.com
- https://api.mycompany.com/myproduct

See what you think and post any questions - I will then tidy up my answer a bit more. At Curity we will be doing more work on this theme so keep an eye on our resources.

Comment: Okay I think I finally understand this, thanks. I am just wondering about simpler approach: instead of using token handler with all cookies session management, on API side just implement endpoint "api.example.com/login/end?authorization_code=xxx" which would call authorization (OAUTH2) server to exchange authorization_code for access token/refresh token and just return those tokens in cookies. Also add simple middleware that reads bearer token from cookie. It sounds like adding 10 lines of code to our current API GW implementation (.net + GQL). Are there any disadvantages of such approach?

Comment: That sounds right, though you also need to deal with CORS, expiry, refresh etc. You'll also need to think it through from the viewpoint of multiple SPAs and APIs, since different cookies and API routes per SPA are typically needed.

Comment: Is Curity TokenHandler solution separate from IdentityServer solution (can it be used with other OAUTH server than the one from Curity for example)? We have also our own GraphQL API GW written in .net core and deployed to k8s that just makes GRPC requests to internal services. I am wondering if you have TokenHandler plugins for .net core? I think in our approach we would need OAUTH proxy directly in our GQL API GW and OAUTH agent with session mgmt deployed separately. I mean I am not sure where in TokenHandler pattern there is a place for GraphQL API GW?

Comment: It's a standards based pattern - with an HTTPS interface - we don't have .NET versions right now, but we will later in 2022 I think. In your own gateway you can follow the pattern in [this OAuth proxy plugin](https://github.com/curityio/nginx-lua-oauth-proxy-plugin/blob/master/plugin/oauth-proxy.lua).